# Use emmet plugin with jade document in PHPStorm

Tags: html, pug, phpstorm, template-engine, emmet

I just started using Jade language as a template language and HTML pre-processor. 
I always look how to speed up my coding, so for the plain HTML I use Emmet to generate CSS and HTML quickly.
Is there a way to do the same in Jade document, for instance when I write

```
ul>li*5
```

And click tab, I will get this in Jade:

```
ul
  li
  li
  li
  li
  li
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/237, there is Jade support for sublime text. Not sure about the PHPStorm version.

Comment: i can confirm it works in sublime text more or less.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no support for Emmet in for jade in PHPStorm. Please feel free to file a request for this feature to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB